# How would I implement Arrays into this code

Tags: c++, arrays

I've been a lurker of this site and now I need help with implementing arrays into this code. I'm not sure how to add the code into here so here's

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
//Named constants – residential customers
const double RES_BILL_PROC_FEES = 4.50;
const double RES_BASIC_SERV_COST = 20.50;
const double RES_COST_PREM_CHANNEL = 7.50;
//Named constants – business customers
const double BUS_BILL_PROC_FEES = 15.00;
const double BUS_BASIC_SERV_COST = 75.00;
const double BUS_BASIC_CONN_COST = 5.00;
const double BUS_COST_PREM_CHANNEL = 50.00;
int main()
{
    //Variable declaration
    int accountNumber;
    char customerType;
    int numOfPremChannels;
    int numOfBasicServConn;
    double amountDue;
    int rescount = 0, buscount = 0;
    double ressum = 0.00, bussum = 0.00;
    double resavg, busavg;
    ifstream fin;
    ofstream fout;
    //open input file
    fin.open("custin.txt", ios::in);
    if (fin.fail()) {
        cout << "Unable to open file " << endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    //open ouput file
    fout.open("custout.txt", ios::out);
    fout << fixed << showpoint;
    fout << setprecision(2);
    fout << "This program computes a cable "
         << "bill." << endl;
    //read from input file
    while (!fin.eof()) {
        //read customer type from file
        fin >> customerType;
        //read account number from file
        fin >> accountNumber;

        //If customer type is residential
        if (customerType == 'r' || customerType == 'R') {
            //read number of prem channels from file
            fin >> numOfPremChannels;
            amountDue = RES_BILL_PROC_FEES + RES_BASIC_SERV_COST + numOfPremChannels * RES_COST_PREM_CHANNEL;

            //write into output file
            fout << "Account number: " << accountNumber << endl;
            fout << "Amount due: $" << amountDue << endl
                 << endl;
            //compute running average of residential cusomer's amount due
            rescount += 1;
            ressum += amountDue;
            resavg = ressum / rescount;
        }

        //If customer type is business
        else if (customerType == 'b' || customerType == 'B') {
            //read number of service connection from file
            fin >> numOfBasicSevConn;

            //read number of prem channels from file
            fin >> numOfPremChannels;
            if (numOfBasicServConn <= 10)
                amountDue = BUS_BILL_PROC_FEES + BUS_BASIC_SERV_COST + numOfPremChannels * BUS_COST_PREM_CHANNEL;
            else
                amountDue = BUS_BILL_PROC_FEES + BUS_BASIC_SERV_COST + (numOfBasicServConn - 10) * BUS_BASIC_CONN_COST + numOfPremChannels * BUS_COST_PREM_CHANNEL;
            fout << "Account number: " << accountNumber << endl; //Step 7f
            fout << "Amount due: $" << amountDue << endl
                 << endl; //Step 7f

            //compute running average of business cusomer's amount due
            buscount += 1;
            bussum += amountDue;
            busavg = bussum / buscount;
        }
        else
            fout << "Invalid customer type.in " << accountNumber << endl; //Step 8
    }
    fout << endl
         << "Average Due for residential Customer " << resavg << endl;
    fout << endl
         << "Average Due for Business Customer " << busavg << endl;
    fin.close();
    fout.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you were a lurker on this site, you would know that you need to provide [mcve], with exact problem description, instead of linking to external sites.

Comment: Code goes into the question, not on some off-site text file hosting service.

Comment: Where do you need to add arrays? For what purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to add arrays in C++. The first way is to specify the type of the array (int, double, float, char, string) and then specify the length of the array and type all the values until you get to the length. For example `int arr[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};` For the other way you don't need to specify the length so that means you can put as many elements in the array as you like but you still need the data type and variable name like `int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34};`. Remember though in programming we start counting from 0.

Comment: Thanks this helped me and sorry about linking another site I wasn't able to post the whole code for some reason.